# How to render set of Array objects and images in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

Here is this ModuleCardData.js

```
  {
    name: 'Smart Attendance',
    summary: 'Keep parents updated with live Attendance and monthly reports',
    image: '{Attendance}',
  },
  {
    name: 'Parents Communication Module',
    summary:
      'Chat with parents anytime, anywhere. Disable chat when you are busy.',
    image: '{Communication}',
  },
  {
    name: 'Class Management',
    summary: 'Forget tons of paperwork and manage your institute completely.',
    image: '{Class}',
  },
  {
    name: 'Fee Records',
    summary:
      'Automatic reminders and recepits of installments for student due fees.',
    image: '{Fee}',
  },
  {
    name: 'Insightful student reports.',
    summary: 'Personalized reports for all your students.',
    image: '{Stats}',
  },
  {
    name: 'Online Tests',
    summary:
      'Conduct your online tests powered with automatic checking and solution.',
    image: '{Test}',
  },
];
```

and my ModuleCards.js file.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './ModuleCards.scss';

//Img import.

import Attendance from '../Common/assets/images/smartattendance.svg';
import Communication from '../Common/assets/images/parents.svg';
import Test from '../Common/assets/images/test1.svg';
import Stats from '../Common/assets/images/reports.svg';
import Class from '../Common/assets/images/classmgmt.svg';
import Fee from '../Common/assets/images/fee.svg';

//Data import

import card from '../Common/data/ModuleCardsData.js';

class ModuleCards extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const cardData = { ...this.props.cardData };
    return (
      <div className="module-card">
        <img src={this.cardData.image} />
        <h3>{this.cardData.name}</h3>
        <p>{this.cardData.summary}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ModuleCards.propTypes = {};
export default ModuleCards;
```

How can I correctly render the array from ModuleCardData file?

I've tried many solutions like dealing with props, etc.
Especially those images, is that the right way to make those images render or should I used another method?

Comment: ```export const cardData = [
  {
    name: 'Smart Attendance',
    summary: 'Keep parents updated with live Attendance and monthly reports',
    image: '{Attendance}',
  },
  ```  this part is missing from modulesCardData.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, first of all, you should export you array from ModuleCardData.js like this

```
const myArrayCardData = [{
    name: 'Smart Attendance',
    summary: 'Keep parents updated with live Attendance and monthly reports',
    image: '{Attendance}',
  },
  {
    name: 'Parents Communication Module',
    summary:
      'Chat with parents anytime, anywhere. Disable chat when you are busy.',
    image: '{Communication}',
  }]

export default myArrayCardData;
```

Then, in your react file, you can do something like

```
import cardData from './ModuleCardData';
```

and then in your render method, do something like:

```
  render() {
    return cardData.map(card => {
      return (<div className="module-card">
        <img src={card.image} />
        <h3>{card.name}</h3>
        <p>{card.summary}</p>
      </div>)
    })
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. I feel so much as a noob now.

Comment: you shouldn't bro. we are all learning all the time. im glad it worked.